# Why JNI GetByteArrayElements does not reserve pixel stride

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, java-native-interface

I need to pass a YUV_420_8888 image from Android to C++ for processing. So, I take the image planes, convert them to `ByteArray`, then send them to C++ function.

```kotlin
val yBuffer: ByteBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer            
val uBuffer: ByteBuffer = image.planes[1].buffer
val vBuffer: ByteBuffer = image.planes[2].buffer
val yByteArray = ByteArray(yBuffer.remaining())
val uByteArray = ByteArray(uBuffer.remaining())
val vByteArray = ByteArray(vBuffer.remaining())
yBuffer.get(yByteArray)
uBuffer.get(uByteArray)
vBuffer.get(vByteArray)
return NativeCppClass::process(yByteArray, uByteArray, vByteArray)
```

`y` plane has pixel stride 1. `u` and `v` planes have pixel stride 2. When I look at `uByteArray` and `vByteArray`, they are viewing the same memory block, with `v` plane starts before `u` plane. More particular, they look like this, for example:

```kotlin
vByteArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
uByteArray =    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Based on this, I expect we have this statement below. Let's call it `(*)` for easier reference:

```kotlin
uByteArray.begin - vByteArray.begin = 1; // begin is just a way to express the starting point of a byte array
```

I also have a `ByteArray_JNI` to convert `ByteArray` from Kotlin into a class called `CppByteArray`. They look like this:

```cpp
class ByteArray_JNI {
public:
    using CppType = CppByteArray;
    using JniType = jbyteArray;
    using Boxed = ByteArray_JNI;

   static CppType toCpp(JNIEnv *jniEnv, JniType byteArray) { 
      
      return CppType{byteArray, jniEnv};
    }
}

class CppByteArray {
public: 
    CppByteArray(jbyteArray data, JNIEnv *env) : array_(env, data) {
        jboolean copied = false;
        buffer_ = (uint8_t *)env->GetByteArrayElements(data, &copied);
        // copied out param is false at this stage, so no copy
        size_ = env->GetArrayLength(data);
    }
    const uint8_t* data() const {
      return buffer_; 
    }
private: 
    djinni::GlobalRef<jbyteArray> array_;
    uint8_t *buffer_ = nullptr;
    jsize size_ = 0;
}
```

However, statement `(*)` above is not true inside C++:

```cpp
class NativeCppClass {
public:
    static CppByteArray process(CppByteArray &&y_array, CppByteArray &&u_array, CppByteArray &&v_array) {
          auto u_begin = u_array.data(); 
          auto v_begin = v_array.data();
          // u_begin - v_begin = 462848 (not 1 as expected). My image has dimensions 1280x720, just in case it is related to the number 462848. 
         return something; 
    }
}
```

Why `u_begin - v_begin = 462848` but not 1? `GetByteArrayElements` does not perform a copy in this case. The output parameter `copied` is false after calling `GetByteArrayElements`.

Comment: Wild guess: GetByteArrayElements copied the elements

Comment: That's not the case here. `GetByteArrayElements` has an out param `copied`. It is false after the call to `GetByteArrayElements`. I will update the question

Comment: In the YUV420 format, the u and v values are interleaved. It seems that you tried to obtain a pointer to the start point of u with GetByteArrayElements, but you didn't release it with ReleaseByteArrayElements. I am not sure if it is valid to access v without releasing u.  P.S. The value 462848 is close to 1280 * 720 / 2, the space that uv takes

Comment: @Joe_Bao can you elaborate on what should be done?

Comment: @no_name for NV12 Image, the necessary info will be width, height, stride_luma, stride_chroma, ptr_luma, ptr_chroma. I think you may try to allocate memory for _buffer after GetArrayLength, and save the ptr that GetByteArrayElements returns in another local variable.  uint8_t* ptr_bytes = (uint8_t *)env->GetByteArrayElements(data, &copied);  size_ = env->GetArrayLength(data); _buffer = new uint8_t[size_]; memcpy(_buffer, ptr_bytes, size_);env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(data, ptr_bytes, JNI_ABORT) And in deconstruction function, check whether size_ is zero, if not, release the memory.

Comment: get() indeed does the copy. Here is my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71793829/17258880)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ByteBuffer documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/nio/ByteBuffer#get_2, `get` copies the bytes into destination array. In this case, `yByteArray`, `uByteArray` and `vByteArray` are copied from the buffers. This explains why the offset in pointers is not 1.